# Can Borg identify members of the Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg, star-trek-q

In "Q Who" and "Q2," one or more Borg Drones find themselves in the same space as a member of the Q Continuum. On the Enterprise in "Q Who," Q is in Engineering, and on Voyager's bridge, Q's son is present when the Borg invade.

Assuming that the Q were not actively hiding their true identities, would Borg Drones be able to identify them on sight? There was no attempt by the Borg to assimilate Q's son, so that may imply that the Collective knows better than to mess with a Q.

Comment: Well, they couldn't identify holograms on sight in _First Contact_, and you’d think that would be easier than identifying a Q. But I don’t know.

Comment: *There was no attempt by the Borg to assimilate Q's son, so that may imply that the Collective knows better than to mess with a Q.*  This could be the case, but we do also know that, so long as individuals are not posing a threat, the Borg ignore them, almost as a rule.  The Borg assimilate groups / species / cultures / technology rather than individuals.

Comment: The Q must hide their true identify - it is established we can't see "the real them." Q's entrance intro to TNG (Farpoint) includes many forms but never his "natural state." Even so, it seems obvious, the Borg could identify the being in front of them as they appeared to exist. There is one exception: Guinan. As an El Aurian she seemed quite able to identify Q but we have no idea if it was him as an individual or his entire -- uh -- continuum. (Though speculation was her ability was a side-effect of the Nexus). The question really is, "Do Borg have extrasensory Q-perception?" Seems like no.

Answer (score 6):

With any other race I'd say they probably could, but the Q themselves aren't exactly bound by the normal rules. In both [All Good Things](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28episode%29) and [Tapestry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_%28episode%29) we see that Q appears in a way that only those he wants to see him can (in both cases it's just Picard). So if the Borg were around, it's entirely possible that the Q would make themselves imperceptible to the Borg.

But, assuming they were perceptible, my bet is they would merely be seen as a normal human (remember when Q was kicked out in [Deja Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_%28episode%29) and was made human). As to why they were ignored, the Borg tend to focus on threats first (the only possible exception was in First Contact, where they were trying to take over the ship). None of the Q were armed or engaging them so they didn't bother with them. Also, it's unlikely they would be recognized. The Q take many forms and the Borg aren't interested in identities generally (Picard was the first individual they expressed any interest in).

Comment: I wrote in the OP that we were to assume that the Q were not actively hiding their identities.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon Sorry bout that. Expanded my answer to cover that

Comment: If the Borg aren't interested in individuals, then why was Janeway a picosecond away from becoming a Drone?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : The Borg Queen felt continually threatened by Janeway and her scheming.  The Borg ignore individuals but neutralize threats.